# Styling isn't applying in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide the text of a button and show a spinner in its place while processing something. However no styling is applied even though the classes get properly toggled to the right value as I see on the Developer Tools.

```js
function toggleSpinner() {
    $('button span').toggleClass('display-none');
    $('button .fa-spinner').toggleClass('display-none');
}

function generateGrid(size) {
    let arr = getRandomNumbers(size);

    toggleSpinner(); // <--- HIDE TEXT SHOW SPINNER
    $('.grid').empty();

    let html = '';
    arr.forEach((element) => {
        html += '<div class="box">' + element.toLocaleString() + '</div>';
    });
    $('.grid').append(html);

    toggleSpinner(); // <--- HIDE SPINNER SHOW TEXT
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```html
<button>
    <span>Generate Random Numbers</span>
    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin display-none"></i>
</button>
```

Generating the grid sometimes takes like 3 seconds depending on the size of the grid and during that time, I would like to show the spinner on the button instead of the text.

### More Info

The first time `toggleSpinner()` gets called, I expect the button to only display a spinning icon without the text. The second time `toggleSpinner()` gets called, I expect the spinning icon to go away and the button's text to show up again.

What's happening is that even though the classes get toggled, it's like the browser isn't repainting the page until everything is done so in effect, it's like `toggleSpinner()` gets called twice which results to the same classes from the beginning resulting in no changes to the button.

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Comment: @ScottMarcus CSS is just a simple `.display-none { display: none; }` - the script is just toggling that class.

Comment: @Cjmarkham not sure what that edit is for.. doesn't really help demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I've added a runnable snippet based on your code and it appears to work correctly

Comment: It shows that the classes do get swapped out and the CSS styling does get applied

Comment: @Cjmarkham I already mentioned in the question that the classes do get toggled properly. You missed the most critical part which is the loop that usually takes a while to finish.

Comment: You said the styling never gets applied...

Comment: @Cjmarkham right the classes do get toggled correctly so I expect the styles to apply but nothing changes in the button.

Comment: Which is why I added the example to your question. It showed that the CSS does get applied when the classes are toggled, leading me to believe that the issue may lie somewhere else.

Comment: I suspect that `generateGrid` is blocking the event loop, which prevents rendering the page with the spinner. I would check if running `generateGrid` from a timer or requesetAnimationFrame makes a difference.

Comment: @traktor That's also my suspicion but I don't know how to do that. I usually use AJAX to retrieve data and do the toggling before request is sent and after the data is received. Since that's asychronous it works.. but with this, this is synchronous so it's not repainting the way I'm used to seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to the DOM are not being rendered because generating the grid is blocking the event loop. Hence running `generateGrid` asynchronously should solve the issue. However just running it as an asynchronous function and waiting for it to finish (using `await`), or putting the code directly in a promise handler, risks putting processing in the microtask queue - which also blocks the event loop.

This example simulate "generating the grid" by simply running a loop for 3 seconds. It is called from a timer call with an additional callback argument to signal when it has done. The calling function, `makeGrid` returns a promise this is fulfilled when processing has completed:

```js
"use strict";
function toggleSpinner() {
    $('button span').toggleClass('display-none');
    $('button .fa-spinner').toggleClass('display-none');
}

function makeGrid(size) {
    toggleSpinner(); // show spinner
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        setTimeout( generateGrid, 0, size, function() {
            toggleSpinner(); // hide spinner
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
function generateGrid( size, done) {
   // dummied code just to run synchonously for 3 seconds
    const end = Date.now() + 3000;
    while( Date.now() < end);
    done();  // callback when done
}


function test() {
   console.log( "calling makeGrid");
    makeGrid(1).then( ()=>console.log("makeGrid finished"));
}
```

```css
.display-none {
   display: none;
}
.fa-spinner:before {
   content: "⏳";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<!-- body-html -->
<button>
    <span>Generate Random Numbers</span>
    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin display-none"></i>
</button>
<p>
<button onclick="test()">test</button> <-- click here to test
```

Comment: I abandoned my approach and used AJAX to fetch the grid so I no longer have this problem. But I think from reading your solution this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's rudamentary and there are probably better ways but one option is to take the first `toggleSpinner` out of the method and use a timeout, which then calls your `generateGrid` function. This gives the CSS and class toggles time to do their thing before the render blocking of the `generateGrid` happens.

```js
function toggleSpinner() {
    $('button span').toggleClass('display-none');
    $('button .fa-spinner').toggleClass('display-none');
}

function getRandomNumbers(size) {
  return new Array(size).fill('foo')
}

function generateGrid(size) {
    let arr = getRandomNumbers(size);

    $('.grid').empty();

    let html = '';
    arr.forEach((element) => {
        html += '<div class="box">' + element.toLocaleString() + '</div>';
    });
    $('.grid').append(html);
    
    toggleSpinner()
}

$('button').on('click', () => {
  toggleSpinner()
  setTimeout(() => { generateGrid(100000); }, 1000)
  
})
```

```css
.display-none { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
    <span>Generate Random Numbers</span>
    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin display-none">SPINNING</i>
</button>
<div class="grid"></div>
```